# What is the implication of mapping BSS to the Virtual Memory Segment 0?

Tags: linux, memory-management

I read from [her](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1)e that 
"The BSS segment of executable files isn't stored on disk, and the kernel maps the zero page to the BSS address range."
Can someone please provide a detailed answer about what is going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"The BSS segment of executable files isn't stored on disk"

Because the BSS segment is expected to be zero-initialized when a new process is created, and just storing a bunch of zeros in the executable file wastes space, the executable simply indicates where the BSS segment should start and how big it should be.

"and the kernel maps the zero page to the BSS range."

When the kernel is building a new process from the executable, it creates a mapping for the BSS range to the zero page, which is a static (virtual) page of all zeros. The mapping will have copy-on-write set on it, so the first time the new process writes to one of the BSS pages, a real copy of the static zero page will be allocated in another memory page before the write is allowed to complete.

This (a) saves space in the executable and (b) avoids actually allocating BSS pages that may never get touched by the process, thus saving memory usage, while still providing the guarantee that the BSS segment in every process appears to be zero-initialized as required.

Comment: Great answer! Where can I get awesome knowledge like you?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think searching online is probably a good start - look for linux kernel/internals books that have good reviews on Amazon and other places. The "best books" are constantly changing, so the ones I've got on my shelf aren't necessarily that great anymore. I would also highly suggest learning the internals of another Unix variant - Solaris for example, or AIX or ... If you can claim a good understanding of the differences between Linux and something else, that shows you have a reasonable grasp of the topic.

Comment: Question - Why would I save BSS segment in the executable? These are just the variables that are declared but not initialized in the code. do you in the process memory map in the main memory?